How to create a custom model with Hugginface PreTrainedModel
I'm trying to create a simple model with the code below, taken almost directly from the documentation, and receiving an error
import torch
from transformers import PretrainedConfig, PreTrainedModel
from typing import List

class TextIntentConfig(PretrainedConfig):
    def __init__(self, num_classes: int = 1, **kwargs):
        self.num_classes=num_classes
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class TextIntentModel(PreTrainedModel):
    config_class = TextIntentConfig
    def __init__(self,config):
        super().__init__(config)
        self.config = config

config = TextIntentConfig(100)
model = TextIntentModel(config)
model.save_pretrained("custom_text_intent")

new_model = TextIntentModel.from_pretrained("./custom_text_intent")
print(new_model)

and the error is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/<path_to_venv>/intent/src/text_intent.py", line 18, in <module>
    model.save_pretrained("custom_text_intent")
  File "/<path_to_venv>/intent/lib/python3.12/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 2538, in save_pretrained
    model_to_save.config.torch_dtype = str(dtype).split(".")[1]
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

I would expect that I have to change the type for a torch config or variable, but it's not clear where, and the source code wasn't very helpful.
Does anybody have an idea where I went wrong?
